# SQL Server add auto serial id to additional field during insert

Tags: sql-server

I have an insert statement in a stored procedure who's primary key is a serial id. I want to be able to populate an additional field in the same table during the same insert statement with the serial id used for the primary key. Is this possible?

Unfortunately this is a solution already in place... I just have to implement it.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine a reason why you would want a copy of the key in another column.  But in order to do it, I think you'll need to follow your update with a statement to get the value of the identity key, and then an update to put that value in the other column.  Since you're already in a stored procedure, it's probably ok to have a few extra statements, instead of doing it in the very same one.

```
DECLARE @ID INT;
INSERT INTO TABLE_THINGY (Name, Address) VALUES ('Joe Blow', '123 Main St');
SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
UPDATE TABLE_THINGY SET IdCopy = @Id WHERE ID = @ID
```

If it's important that this be done every single time, you might want to create a Trigger to do it; beware, however, that many people hate triggers because of the obfuscation and difficulty in debugging, among other reasons.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Comment: Thanks cindyH... no idea either. Thanks for you feedback. I thought about just using IDENT_CURRENT( ) + 1 but would need to test if the identity column had been updated yet or not.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it is odd that you would replicate the key within the same table but with that said you could use a trigger, thus making it have no impact to current insert statements.

The below trigger is "After Insert" so technically it happens milliseconds after the insert if you truly wanted it to happen at the same time you would use a FOR INSERT instead and just replicate the logic used to create the serial id field into the new field.

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerName ON dbo.tableName 
    AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
   update dbo.tableName set newField = inserted.SerialId where serialId = inserted.SerialId
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a computed column that just returns the id column.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Products 
(
    ProductID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
  , OtherProductID AS ProductID
);
```

Having said that, data should only live in one place and to duplicate it in the same table is just a wrong design.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use the ***same*** insert statement for identity Id and copy that auto generated Id to the same row.

Multi-Statement using `OUTPUT inserted` or Trigger is your best bet.